# How to read from xml file without /n/t/t myValue \n\t\t

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Im reading from a xml and my values seem to come all right except with \n\t\t wrapping them... presumably something to do with spacing and stuff... how do i tell C# to ignore this?

Comment: Please post some code so that we can help.

Comment: post some of the xml too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that your XML looks something like this:

```
<foo>
    <bar>
        baz
    </bar>
</foo>
```

While that may look pretty for a person, the XML parser is [required](http://www.xml.com/axml/target.html#sec-white-space) to preserve all whitespace. Nor is the parser permitted to combine whitespace that appears on either side of an element (so in this case the DOM representation of `foo` has three children: a Text node containing only whitespace, an Element node for bar, and another Text node containing only whitespace).

Bottom line is that Fredrik's answer is the correct one, but I figured that the rationale behind the behavior was important.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to call the [`Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) method on the returned string? That should strip off line feeds, tabs and spaces from the start and end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue in my java program. But not in C#.

This suggestion will help someone.

**Below steps I did.**

```
1. Before parsing I read the complete XML as a String.
2. Trim the string
3. replace all "\n" to ""
4. replace all "\t" to ""
```

Then, I parsed perfectly.